# How to maintain high performance in a medical production database with millions of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have an application that is used to chart patient data during an ICU stay (Electronic record).
Patients are usually connected to several devices (monitors, ventilator, dialysis etc.)
that send data in a one minute interval. An average of 1800 rows are inserted per hour per patient.

Until now the integration enginge recieves the data and stores it in files on a dedicated drive.
The application reads it from there and plots it in graphs and data grids.

As there's a requirement for analysis we're thinking about writing the incoming signals immediately into the DB.
But there're a lot of concerns with respect to performance. Especially in this work environment people are very sensitive when it comes to performance.

Are there any techniques besides proper indexing to mitigate a possbile performance impact?
I'm thinking of a job to load the data into a dedicated table or maybe even into another database e.g. after 1 Month after the record was closed.

Any experiences how to keep the production DB small and lightweight?

Comment: Replicate the database and do all analysis on the replicated database.  Try to avoid touching the operational system for any non-operational purpose.

Comment: don't do analysis in the same database. If you have to, you need to think in a solution to avoid degradation in the operational side, for example using oracle resource manager. If you can replicate, do that. Depending on your environment and capabilities, active data guard could be an option.

Comment: I think i wasnt clear enough about the analysis. Of course analysis should be done on a replicated DB, but until now there is no device data in the DB to analyize. Thats why we want to write it in the DB. Qudstion is if it would affect the Performance of the application after several months or years and how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how many patients you have in you ICU unit but unless you have thousands of patients you should not have any problems - as long as you stick to inserts, use bind variables and do have as many freelists as necessary. Insert will only create  locks on the free list. So you can do as many parallel insert as there are freelists available to determine a free block where to write the data to. You may want to look at the discussion over ra TKyte's site
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:950845531436

Generally speaking 1.800 records per hours (or 10-20 times that) is not a lot for any decent sized Oracle db. If you are really fancy you could choose to partition based on the patient_id. This would be specifically useful if you:

- Access the data only for one patient at a time because you can just skip all other partitions.
- If you want to remove the data for a patient en bloc once he leaves ICU. Instead of DELETEING you could just drop the patients partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Define "immediately". One of the best things you can do to improve `INSERT` performance is to batch the commands instead of running them one-at-a-time.

Every SQL statement has overhead - sending the statement to the database, parsing it (remember to use bind variables so that you don't have to hard parse each statement), returning a message, etc. In many applications, that overhead takes longer than the actual `INSERT`.

You only have to do a small amount of batching to significantly reduce that overhead. Running an `INSERT ALL` with two rows instead of two separate statements reduces the overhead by 1/2, running with three rows reduces overhead by 2/3, etc. Waiting a minute, or even a few seconds, can make a big difference.

As long as you avoid the common row-by-row blunders, an Oracle database with "millions" of rows is nothing to worry about. You don't need to think about cryptic table settings or replication yet.